# Cómo integrar ajax a if PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo este problema, que la verdad no logro hacer funcionar, quiero que esto:

```
if ($quediaes=="Sun" && (0 <= $quehoraes && $quehoraes <= 15 || (19<= $quehoraes && $quehoraes <= 23)) ) {
    echo'<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
}
```

Un `if` php normal, se actualice, es decir, se edite el link automaticamente sin recargar la web, esto funciona con ajax, pero yo no lo logré, todo lo que hice dañó mi código, por eso vengo a pedir una guía, o ducumentación.

PD: este es el IF que se muestra de "16 a 18"

```
elseif ($quediaes=="Sun" && (16 <= $quehoraes && $quehoraes <= 18)) {
    echo'<a href="/elegir.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
}
```

Como ven, esto asi funciona, pero hay que recargar la página, y yo busco que cambie de un `if` a otro sin recargar.

Answer (score 2):

Como te ha comentado @Javi Ps deberías plantearlo de otra forma; En mi opinión, y viendo que ya tenías pensado utilizar ajax, deberías olvidarte de php y hacerlo directamente mediante javascript:

```js
function generarEnlace(){
//creo una nueva fecha para obtener la fecha actual
var fecha = new Date();
//con getDay obtengo el dia (de 0 a 6 siendo 0 domingo)
//Y con getHours se obtiene la hora (0-23)
if (fecha.getDay()==0 && (0 <= fecha.getHours() && fecha.getHours() <= 15 || (19<= fecha.getHours() && fecha.getHours() <= 23)) ) {

//Aqui obtengo el div con id enlace para insertar el <a>

    document.getElementById("enlace").innerHTML='<a class="waves-       effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';

}else if (fecha.getDay()==0 && (16 <= fecha.getHours() && fecha.getHours() <= 18)) {

    document.getElementById("enlace").innerHTML='<a href="/elegir.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';

//este else lo he puesto por que en tu ejemplo preguntas si es domingo y sino no se iba a ejecutar
}else{
  document.getElementById("enlace").innerHTML='<p>Hoy no es domingo</p>';
}
}
//con setInterval hago que la función se ejecute cada 60 segundos
setInterval("generarEnlace()", 60000);
```

```html
<div id="enlace">

</div>
```

Espero que te sirva! Por último decirte que para mayor seguridad, también deberías de validar estos horarios en la parte servidor mediante php.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de escribir ese código, ahora lo voy a probar bien, pero tengo dos preguntas, la hora, por ejemplo dice "de 19 a 23" se muestro cierta cosa, eso según que, a lo que me refiero es, según la hora que tenga la pc del que ingresa, segun el pais, porque mi web necesitaría que eso funcionara desde todo el mundo, osea que si en mi pais son las 19 en españa, por ejemplo serían las 23 o las 00 no se bien, el caso, es que necesito que se ejecute en todo el mundo

Comment: Hola Mati te dejo un enlace a una [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) de Date en javaScript por si tienes alguna duda más. De todas formas, contestando a tu pregunta,  al instanciar el `Date()` se coge automáticamente la fecha y hora locales (la pc del que ingresa), por lo que no habría ningún problema en todo el mundo.